# Roadmap for learning Electrical Engineering

Tags: basic

I am just starting to learn electrical engineering, but I am confused about what I should do. Should I be reading about it, taking online classes, or just make projects? If possible can you provide me with a roadmap of what I should do in order to best learn about electrical engineering? I am really interested in making exciting projects related to the field. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make projects. Read app notes and datasheets.

Comment: Why do you want to learn electrical engineering? There are a few different paths somewhat dependent on your reasons.

Comment: Start with the fundamentals and make sure you understand them as they are key to everything else. Beyond that, do some projects and read some of the better books.

Comment: Questions soliciting opinions are closed so, here's your first lesson to be a good EE - read and understand the detail very carefully and that includes sites about EE such as this one: [Don't ask questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Also take some classes involving electronics. Many highschools offer a limited selection, as well as vocational schools, community colleges, etc. This might vary globally, and not even be possible this semester. Also see [MIT OCW](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-002-circuits-and-electronics-spring-2007/) on electronics. There is much to learn!

Comment: You need to learn from reading and  circuits.  Real circuits cost money and require expertise to assemble.  So the best bet for you is to do a lot of circuit work in simulation first.  QUCS for example is a simple starter-level simulator.  Once you get some experience with a simulated circuit then you may build it.  Simulation will save you a lot of time and money lost on real circuits that didn't work.

Comment: You can begin with **Fundamentals of Electric Circuits, by Charles Alexander**. This book is one of enjoyable books to start . It helped me a lot !

Comment: It's a lot to get started with, but I'd buy an Arduino starter kit and start operating some devices with a microcontroller.  Next, I'd go look for an online course to learn KiCad or Altium to build boards.   There's a lot you can learn about circuits in abstract with simulations, but in many lots of that is uneccesary to build gadgets that can do cool things -- a lot of that design work has been done already.

Answer (score 2):

**Do both!** Do projects as well as reading literature.

You don't want to only sink into literature, or you will be bored and frustrated quite quickly (well, most likely at least, it depends on what you are really interested in the most). You also don't want to do only projects from the internet without any real explanation of theory, otherwise you will probably never understand the fundamentals behind your projects.

If you really want to learn all the basics I can recommend you the book [The Art of Electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics). It is quite impressive (in terms of number of pages) and written for courses at Havard, but that should not mislead you: The book is fantastically written, very well explained and includes a lot of practical examples. You won't get bored with theory. In fact the book has gained a decent readership from the maker scene.

And for the projects aspect: The internet is full of little and big projects for every level of difficulty. Just look around for tutorials and projects that you are interested in and start experimenting.
Analog Devices for example offers [this set of tutorials with practial courses](https://www.analog.com/en/education/courses-and-tutorials.html). This should also cover a lot of the basics that would be explained in the above mentions book, but in less detail.

Answer (score 1):

Build some bipolar ac_coupled multistage audio amplifiers. I used several examples in my stackX answers.

And then learn about how transformers and generators and motors ad high power lines
can interfere with the audio signals.

Then think about the fun involved.

Comment: May be add "if you're interested in amplifiers and analog electronics, ..." in the front. When I started in EE, I was **not at all** attracted to audio stuff (and I'm still not, to me it is a solved matter). My first projects were about home automation (alluring to me at the time: very ad-hoc, and quite useful).

Answer (score 0):

Find out what you are most interested in:

- ac
- electro-mechanics
- analogue
- digital
- microprocessors
- embedded programming
- radio frequency
- radio amateur
- linear
- switch-mode

  etc.

Then concentrate on that specific field and master it starting with basic principals.

The physics classes at Khan Academy has a sound scientific basis.  There may be many more.